# Cosmos DB replication cost

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to set up a Cosmos DB account with a single write region and multiple read regions. I  also want to use autoscaling RU provisioning, so I only pay for what I use (above the floor).

Now if there is zero load I expect the RU cost to be 400 RU multiplied by region count (since 400 RU is the cost floor for autoscaling).

If I perform a write charged at a specific RU cost that I can see in the response, is that only counted once (against the write region), and then the replication only incurs extra costs for egress and storage? Or will the RU cost be multiplied by the region count behind the scenes?

Similarly for reads, is that RU cost only counted once (against the read region), or is it multiplied by the region count?

Under Metrics (Classic), I see that Avg Throughput/s (RU/s) only changes in the write region when writing, but I'm not sure if this reflects the actual charge.

I felt that this was not answered clearly in: [In Cosmos DB, how does geo-replication impact RU consumption of writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68831779/in-cosmos-db-how-does-geo-replication-impact-ru-consumption-of-writes)

Comment: You are going to pay for the highest RU/s consumption in any region across all configured regions. There is no RU per region capability today.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then it seems that replication is going to be more expensive than simply writing to multiple separate single-region databases, unless load is completely uniform. Is that right?

Comment: No. It is the same price and why would you ever want to do that? You'd have to implement your own consistency checker, build failover, etc. Cosmos this is all done for you at no cost.

Answer (score 1):

> The throughput that you have configured for various Azure Cosmos
> databases and containers will be reserved in each of the Azure regions
> associated with your Azure Cosmos database account. If the sum of
> provisioned throughput (RU/sec) configured across all the databases
> and containers within your Azure Cosmos database account (provisioned
> per hour) is T and the number of Azure regions associated with your
> database account is N, then the total provisioned throughput for a
> given hour, for your Azure Cosmos database account is equal to T x N
> RU/sec.

**Provisioned throughput (single write region) costs $0.008/hour per 100 RU/sec and provisioned throughput with multiple writable regions (multi-region writes config) costs $0.016/per hour per 100 RU/sec.**

[image]

Source: [Understand your Azure Cosmos DB bill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/understand-your-bill#billing-example-multi-region-azure-cosmos-account-single-region-writes)

Comment: FYI this question should be closed as a documentation request (there's nothing programming-related here). Also, there's no need to quote exact cost per RU/sec, especially given that the cost varies between geographic region. Lastly, your example is hard-coded to 2 regions, where the text you quoted is for *T* regions.

Comment: Also: Please don't include screenshots of text, as it's unusable for many people, for many reasons. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) covers these reasons really well.